# Where and when did the ".s" suffix for assembly-language source files originate?

Tags: assembly, unix, file-format, compilers, file-system

The closest I was able to find on StackOverflow is [What are .S files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285410/what-are-s-files), in which no answerer addresses *why* we use `.s` for assembly. (And `.S` for preprocessor/macro assembly; and `gcc -S` to produce assembly...)

(By "we," I mean basically the POSIX ecosystem. I understand that the `.s` convention isn't universal. But the convention that *does* exist, must have originated somewhere.)

My wild guesses are:

- `.s` for "source," as opposed to `.o` for "object." Seems to require a timeline where we had 8.3 filesystems before we had high-level languages.
- `.s` for aSsembler, because `.a` was already occupied by Archive.

Anyone got an authoritative answer, or any anecdotal citations to establish a "not after" date?

Comment: Regarding “not after”, [PDP-7 Unix](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/tree/Research-PDP7) used `.s` extensions in 1969.

Comment: Although that might be post-facto, since the source files were reconstructed from [print-outs](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/McIlroy_v0/). V1 Unix definitely used `.s` extensions, they’re mentioned *e.g.* in [the B manpage](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/b).

Comment: Though not on the [*as* manpage](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/as) - so more like a compiler intermediate-file convention rather than an assembler-source convention.

Comment: I guess Unix. DEC systems of the 1960s and later  were in the habit of using mutticharacter (generally 3, but 2 on 12-bit systems) extensions.  Unix tended to brevity in all things.

Comment: IDK, but Unix loved terse names; "ld," "rm," "mv." Single-letter filename extensions are very much in that spirit, and there aren't all that many single letters from which to choose.

Comment: Using upper-case 'S' in gcc for assembler sources to be preprocessed is kind of logical, given that it is an "extended" source, and still just one character. Likewise upper case "C" is used for C++ sources ... at least at some time in some places :-D

Answer (score 23):

I asked Ken Thompson. The s stands for source, because it was the only source at the time.

Comment: That does make some sense, considering that `.o` means an object file.

Comment: This is a _very_ authoritative answer. :) So does that imply that Unix (or some Thompson-authored precursor) _invented_ the `.s` convention, and Thompson got to pick the suffix, ab nihilo? (Along with the more obvious `.o` and `.a`, I suppose?) It wasn't an existing convention at the time?

Comment: Did he explain why it was capitalized (`file.S`)? Or is that a more recent change?

Comment: @ColeTobin: Capital `.S` [indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110745/1424877) source files that need to be preprocessed with [`cpp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cpp) before assembling; lowercase `.s` doesn't get preprocessed. Perhaps cf. the capital `.C` for files preprocessed with [`cfront`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront)?

Answer (score 14):

The V1 Unix [B manpage](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/b) uses `.s` as the extension for intermediate assembly files used during the build. This is the earliest use of `.s` that I can find, and would correspond to November 1971 at the latest.

There were assemblers on systems with file systems before Unix, but none that I’m aware of used `.s`. Some like DECsys don’t appear to have extensions; other used extensions referring to the tool used to process files (*e.g.* `.fap`).

Unix `as` was based on PAL-11R, which used the `PAL` extension (see [page 9-2 of the PAL-11R manual](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/dos-batch/DEC-11-ASDB-D_PAL-11R_Assembler_Programmers_Manual_May71.pdf), thanks [another-dave](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/10854/another-dave)!).